# Selecting match up between team pairs and their relative performance lexicographically

Tags: mysql, sql

We are given a data table called football_tournaments. The table contains the following columns:

1. home_team
2. away_team
3. home_score (no. of goals scored by home team)
4. away_score (no. of goals scored by away team)

We need to write Select SQL query to print the pairs of all teams present in data-set in lexicographical order. We need output to have names of teams, matches played between them and winning percentage of first team in that pair.

I am unable to write the SQL query to pair these teams.

Hypothetical output should look like:

Australia England 31%

England Wales 58% ..... etc.

Comment: This question very much feels like homework/job interview question.. i advice you to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Hint: At first seight the query most likely requires a self join

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to normalize the data so teams are in the same order.  In MySQL, you can do this using `least()` and `greatest()`.  Then, just aggregate:

```
select team1, team2, count(*) as num_games, avg(is_win) as win_ratio
from (select least(home_team, away_team) as team1,
             greatest(home_team, away_team) as team2,
             (case when home_score > away_score and
                        home_team = least(home_team, away_team)
                   then 1
                   when away_score > home_score and
                        away_team = least(home_team, away_team)
                   then 1
                   else 0
              end) as is_win
      from t
     ) t
group by team1, team2;
```